# Any fellow EE defectors?

Tags: discussion

So I've been curious for a little while now, how many defectors there are from the site-that-shall-not-be-named.  I'm one.  Totally dig the trilogy format over their format.  Anyone else?

Comment: ummm...for the uninitiated (such as myself) - I have to know the name of the *site-that-shall-not-be-named* lol

Comment: and, of course, anyone who *was* a defector, would know exactly what you were talking about. So I won't ask.

Comment: Ok, that would be that other expert-sex-change.. site

Comment: What's wrong with mentioning them aloud?

Comment: Just kinda feel dirty...

Comment: I'll say it. experts hyphen exchange dot com. Also, Voldemort!

Comment: oh... *that* EE lol...I never cared much for it...SO is da' bomb

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why yes, I am an electrical engineer who is currently doing software development.

Comment: Ok, I am not the only who thought Electrical Engineer when I first read the title to this question.

Comment: moi aussi, moi aussi

Comment: Winner, for taking the appropriate approach to my lame question...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly a defector. Was active there quite some years ago and gave up after you-know-why, so I didn't exactly deflect as there was a couple of years' gap in between me quitting there and joining the trilogy.

Comment: What is the you-know-why? I'm just curious.

Comment: I can't see paying for their solution base. From what I have seen of some samples, it's not all that. Besides, we have Jon Skeet.